How to rotate procedurally generated objects?- Unreal Engine 5.2
I was recently messing around with Unreal Engine's PCG system, but I noticed something, and that is that static meshes are all rotated in one uniform direction, I would like to rotate each object on the Z axis.
I tried to find a solution but I could not find one.
It's a very simple PCG system:
Code
